# Integration of BigQuery and Dialogflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, dialogflow-es

I'm getting started on Dialogflow and I would like to integrate it with BigQuery.

I have some tables in BigQuery with difference data, for instance a record of alarms that a wind turbine showed during time.

In one of my test cases, let's say I want my chatbot to tell me what alarms were raised in the wind turbine number 5 of my farm, on the 25th of October.

I have already created a chatbot in Dialogflow that asks for all the necessary parameters of the enquiry, such as the wind farm name, the wind turbine number, the date, and the name of the alarm.

My doubt now is how I can send those parameters to BigQuery in order to dig into my tables, extract the required information, and print it in Dialogflow.

I have been looking for documentation or tutorials but nothing came out that could fit my case...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement a [fulfillment](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/fulfillment-overview). It triggers a webhook, for example a Cloud Functions or a Cloud Run service.

This webhook call contains the value gather by your intent and parameters. You have to extract them and perform your process, for example a call to BigQuery. Then format the response and display it on Dialogflow.